# Setting state inside a callback function when using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a component for my pinball game. I have to setState inside the function triggered by the 'on contact' listener. But state is not updating.  Is there another design that i can try?

```
function Pinball(){
  const[score, setScore] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
      //... here I set physics environment and have variable world
      world.on('begin-contact',  function(contact){
             //...
             setScore( score + 1 );
       })
  }, []);

  return (<span>{score}</span>);

}
```

Comment: worst case scenario, wrap it with a promise, resolve the value you need from the callback, await the promise, then setState.

Comment: "I have read that we can not use setState inside nested functions." This simply isn't correct. Also, you're using a state hook, not `setState`.

Comment: I have changed the title of my question. I think my question is clearer now.

Comment: Whats is the problem exactly?

Comment: state is not updating

Comment: it should work. no need for binding as you are not referring with this keyword. closures take care of accessing lexical scope variables. also please check of callback is  executed .

Comment: what is `world`? did you check to see if the callback is executed on `begin-contact` event?

Comment: callback function is called by the listener but state is not updating

Comment: How do you know the state hasn't been updated? do you try to `console.log` it?

Comment: of course I have logged it mate. I have checked a lot about the code, tried a lot...

Comment: the state updater is asynchronous, you can't log it right after you set the state

Comment: I have changed the question returning a span element with the score variable, maybe now you believe...

Comment: For the record, I think what you read about using the state hook was referring to calling `useState`.  That should only be done in the functional component directly, not in a nested function.  But then you can call `setScore` from anywhere in the enclosing scope

Comment: Don't forget to remove the event listener on component unmount or you'll end up with a memory leak pretty quickly. You're allowed to use the state update function anywhere you'd like; it's only the initial invocation of a hook that has rules on where it can and cannot be called.

Comment: Also without the dependencies array it will add a new listener on every re-render

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useCallback` for the callback handler, and useEffect to set the 'begin-contact' event listener. You must pass dependencies in as so:

```js
function Pinball(){
  const[score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const handleBeginContact = useCallback(function(contact){
    setScore( score + 1 );
  }), [score] );
  useEffect(()=>{
    world.on('begin-contact',  handleBeginContact);
  }, [world])

  return <span>{score}</span>;
}
```

You can simplify setScore event further like this:
`setScore(score => score+1)`
Then you don't have to pass the score dependency in.

Additionally, as Dan Pantry said in a comment, you will want to return a function inside the useEffect which unregisters the 'begin-contact' event listener, for example `return () => world.off('begin-contact')`, but that will depend on your implementation of `world`.

Comment: No, only if `world` changes.

Comment: using setScore(score => score+1)  instead of setScore(score + 1 ) solved the problem even without using the useCallback hook. I don't know the reason but it worked.